# Nginx prevent redirect for a single location

Tags: nginx

I have a redirect to force https:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Works great, but I would like to be able to hit a single text file through http using the [echo  module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpEchoModule):

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location /ping {
        echo "http_pong";
    }

    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Unfortunately I can never get to `/ping` as I get the 301 redirect instead.  How can I prevent the global redirect from applying to that single location?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try putting redirect under `location /`, like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location /ping {
        echo "http_pong";
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be aware - **"echo" is deprecated**. Use "return"

```
location / {
  return 200 'http_pong';
```

}